# geom_path generates warrning message after updating R

Tags: r, google-maps, ggplot2, ggmap

I installed a R version 3.3.2 and I have a problem since that. I get following warning messages:

1: `panel.margin` is deprecated. Please use `panel.spacing` property instead
2: Removed 28 rows containing missing values (geom_path).

Example code:

```
require(ggmap)
require(ggplot2)
from <- 'London'
to <- 'Paris'
route_df <- route(from, to, structure = 'route', mode = 'driving')
qmap('London', zoom = 10) +
  geom_path(
    aes(x = lon, y = lat),  colour = 'red', size = 1.5,
    data = route_df, lineend = 'round')
mapdist(from, to)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you also updated `ggplot2` to version 2.2.0? https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2/news.html says _The theme option panel.margin has been deprecated in favour of panel.spacing to more clearly communicate intent._

Comment: I think your `ggmap` is expecting a more up-to-date `ggplot2`.

Comment: Actually I thought about this, but version of ggplot2 is 2.2.0. I also removed both packages (ggmap and ggplot2) and installed it back, unfortunately the warning still appears.